# what is a Host element in Angular for a Component

Tags: angular6

If I have the Component class

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

and index.html is

```
<div>
<my-app></my-app>
</div>
```

What would be the host element of the component? Would it be `<div>` or `<my-app>`? If it is `<my-app>`, is there a way to get access to the `<div>` (parent of `AppComponent`) from `AppComponent`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For Directive, it is the element the directive is attached to. Eg `h1` is the host element in below example

```
<h1 my-directive>
</my-comp>
```

For component, it is the selector of the component. Eg

```
selector: 'my-comp'
template: '
<h1> some heading </h1>
.....

<my-comp></my-comp>  <!-- my-comp is the host element of h1 -->
```